Office Script to delete rows older than today
I have a vehicle booking sheet in excel has column A as the date range. Currently I use macros to delete any rows that are older than Today() when the excel doc is opened to remove old data. We soon will no longer be able to use macro due to security concerns so I am looking for an Office Script alternative to select rows older than Today and then delete the selected rows.
My script knowledge is limited, so I have previously searched for VBA code to perform the task and tweaked to my needs. I am new to Office Script and haven't been able to find a script that will do what I require.

Throw your VBA into ChatGPT and ask it to convert it to Office Scripts.

Pls share sample data.
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.AutoFilter interface


ExcelScript.Range interface getSpecialCells()

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active cell and worksheet.
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const dateCol:string = "Date"
    // Get the first table (ListObject in VBA)
    let table = selectedSheet.getTables()[0];
    table.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
    // get today
    const today = formatDate(new Date());
    console.log(today)
    // Apply custom filter on table table column "Date"
    table.getColumnByName(dateCol).getFilter().applyCustomFilter(`<${today}`);
    const visRng = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible);
    if (visRng) {
        const visAreas = visRng.getAreas().reverse();
        let visRngRefs: string[] = visAreas.map(x => x.getAddress());
        // remove rows 
        visRngRefs.forEach(x => {
            selectedSheet.getRange(x).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
        })
    }
    table.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();
}
// get the string of today, yyyy/MM/dd
function formatDate(date: Date): string {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // Months are zero-indexed
    const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
}

Note: testing is on 2024/10/02.

